# How to hide checkout cart unless logged in bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to hide the cart button in the top right unless the customer is logged in. I have been able to successfully do this for other buttons by editing the `navigation.html` file with:

```
{{/if}}
        {{#if settings.account_creation_enabled}}
```

However, when I try to do this for the cart button I keep getting an error when trying to save the file. The code is:

```
{{/if}}
    {{#if settings.account_creation_enabled}}
    <li class="navUser-item navUser-item--cart">
        {{#if customer}}
        <a
            class="navUser-action"
            data-cart-preview
            data-dropdown="cart-preview-dropdown"
            data-options="align:right"
            href="{{urls.cart}}">
            <span class="navUser-item-cartLabel">{{lang 'common.cart'}}</span> <span class="countPill{{#if cart.items}} countPill--positive{{/if}} cart-quantity">{{cart.quantity}}</span>
        </a>
            {{/if}}
```

I get this error which references the line where the `{{#if` statement starts:

> Template parse error in templates/components/common/navigation.html. Parse error on line 51

I use this exact same code to hide other buttons, but this one not working. Anybody know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're starting your code snippert with `{{/if}}` as that should be the end of the statement. Your code as posted closes an unseen `{{#if` statement and doesn't close the one you've shown.

[BigCommerce Handlebars Control-Flow Helpers](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/handlebars-control-flow-helpers)

This would make more sense:

```
    {{#if settings.account_creation_enabled}}
    <li class="navUser-item navUser-item--cart">
        {{#if customer}}
        <a
            class="navUser-action"
            data-cart-preview
            data-dropdown="cart-preview-dropdown"
            data-options="align:right"
            href="{{urls.cart}}">
            <span class="navUser-item-cartLabel">{{lang 'common.cart'}}</span> <span class="countPill{{#if cart.items}} countPill--positive{{/if}} cart-quantity">{{cart.quantity}}</span>
        </a>
            {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
```